# How to ignore duplicate lines when processing ip addresses from multiple files?

Tags: python, duplicates

I am writing a python script to do ping tests.

1. Based on circuit_id.txt, I will search from testfile1.txt and testfile2.txt
2. If matched, extract IP addresses from testfile1.txt and testfile2.txt
3. Use the extracted IPs to do ping tests
4. In reality, there are hundreds of lines in each file.

Problems:
It duplicates pinging the same IP address. I want each IP address to be pinged once.

circuit_id.txt:

```
11111
22222
```

testfile1.txt:

```
1.1.1.1 circuit ID: 11111 description: ping test
1.1.1.1 circuit ID: 11111 description: public ip
1.1.1.1 circuit ID: 11111 description: secure dns
```

testfile2.txt:

```
8.8.8.8 circuit ID: 22222 description: ping test
8.8.8.8 circuit ID: 22222 description: public ip
8.8.8.8 circuit ID: 22222 description: google dns
```

...
...

Results:

```
11111
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=5.15 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.151/5.151/5.151/0.000 ms

=============================================================

11111
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=4.91 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.913/4.913/4.913/0.000 ms

=============================================================

11111
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=5.08 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.078/5.078/5.078/0.000 ms
```

And my code:

```
import glob
import os
import re

os.system("clear")

def getping(ip):
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ip)

with open('circuit_id.txt','r') as f1:      
    cid = f1.read().splitlines()

for cidnum in cid:
    for filename in glob.glob('testfile[1-2].txt'):
        with open(filename) as f2:
            for linef2 in f2:
                for part in linef2.split():
                    if cidnum in part:
                        pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})') 
                        lst=[] 
                        lst.append(pattern.search(linef2)[0]) 
                        print(cidnum) #print the line number                
                        for ip in lst:
                 
                            getping(ip)

                            print("\n=============================================================\n")
```

I am trying to use Gino's suggestion for using `set` and after googling on how to use set, it still produces duplicate ping results. Pls help point out my mistakes. Here are the codes with `set`:

```
import glob
import os
import re

os.system("clear")

def getping(ip):
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ip)


with open('circuit_id.txt','r') as f1:      
    cid = f1.read().splitlines()


for cidnum in cid:
    for filename in glob.glob('testfile[1-2].txt'):
        with open(filename) as f2:
            for linef2 in f2:
                for part in linef2.split():
                    if cidnum in part:
                        pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})') 
                   
                        set1= set() #using set here
                        set1.add(pattern.search(linef2)[0])

                        print(cidnum) #print the line number                
                        for ip in set1:
                 
                            getping(ip)

                            print("\n=============================================================\n")
```

Comment: You can store the pinged IP addresses in a set, to "remember" them. When you get the next IP address, if it is already in this set, just skip it, and move on the next IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. The problem was you were recreating the set of pinged IP addresses in the innermost loop (`for part in linef2.split()`) and then you were also iterating through it:

```py
for part in linef2.split():
    if cidnum in part:
        ...
        set1= set()       # <--- The set is being recreated :(

        ...
        for ip in set1:   # <--- You ping each IP in the set :(
```

If I understand you correctly, **you want to only ping each IP once**. If it was pinged before, no need to ping it again. So, you need to keep a `set` of all the pinged IPs *for the entire outermost loop*:

```py
pinged_ips = set()  # <---- Move initialization of the set here

for cidnum in cid:
    ...
```

Then, in the innermost loop, before you `ping` the IP, check first if it's already in the set. If it is, skip to the next iteration (don't ping). If it isn't, then do the ping test:

```py
if cidnum in part:
    pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})')

    ip_addr = pattern.search(linef2)[0]
    if ip_addr in pinged_ips:
        # Already pinged this before, just skip to the next iteration
        continue
    else:
        pinged_ips.add(ip_addr)

    print(cidnum)  # print the line number
    getping(ip_addr)
    print("\n=============================================================\n")
```

Here is your script (with some improvements):

```py
# No need to compile the regex pattern every time
ip_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*')

pinged_ips = set()

for cidnum in cid:
    for filename in glob.glob('testfile[1-2].txt'):
        with open(filename) as f2:
            for linef2 in f2:

                # You can do the check in one line:
                # If cidnum is in linef2 and if it begins 
                # with IP address pattern, process it
                if cidnum in linef2 and ip_pattern.search(linef2):

                    # Get the IP address (assuming it's always the 1st part)
                    ip_addr = linef2.split()[0]

                    if ip_addr in pinged_ips:
                        # Already pinged this before, just skip
                        continue
                    else:
                        pinged_ips.add(ip_addr)

                    print(cidnum)  # print the line number
                    getping(ip_addr)
                    print("\n=============================================================\n")
```

Changes:

- Initialize `set` of pinged IPs only once, then skip ping if IP is already in there
- Compile the regex pattern only once since the pattern does not change
- Combine checking if `cidnum` is in the line and if the line has IP address pattern

Output:

```
11111
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=15.767 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 15.767/15.767/15.767/0.000 ms

=============================================================

22222
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=114 time=14.017 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 14.017/14.017/14.017/0.000 ms

=============================================================
```

Comment: Thanks @Gino Mempin for the improved version of the codes and pointing out the problems. I am happy for your valued input.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Gino Mempin, I figure out that I need 4 more lines on my original codes in order to solve the problems. And here is my version (with arrows as the indicator).

```
import glob
import os
import re

os.system("clear")

duplicate = 0 # <--------------------------------

def getping(ip):
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ip)

with open('circuit_id.txt','r') as f1:      
    cid = f1.read().splitlines()

for cidnum in cid:
    for filename in glob.glob('testfile[1-2].txt'):
        with open(filename) as f2:
            for linef2 in f2:
                for part in linef2.split():

                    if cidnum in part:

                        if duplicate == cidnum: # <--------------------------------
                            continue            # <--------------------------------
                            
                        pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})') 
                        lst=[] 
                        lst.append(pattern.search(linef2)[0]) 

                        print(cidnum) #print the line number   

                        duplicate = cidnum     # <-------------------------------- 

                        for ip in lst:
                            getping(ip)
                            print("\n=============================================================\n")
```